# Mario Galaxy loading?

Tags: 3d, loading, game-engine, wii

Super Mario Galaxy experiences virtually no loading time, I heard a long time ago that this is because when Mario flies between planets within a level the game is loading the next few planets at this point. It doesn't load everything at the start.

For reference, this is an example of flying between planets:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Lkk9uM6xQDU#t=123s

I'd like to use a similar technique for a game I'm writing for my final year of my Degree. I do however want to write about it, so does anyone know what this technique may be called and also any other applications using it?

Comment: There isn't a whole lot to each planet in that game.  I wouldn't be surprised if they did no more optimization there than they did in any other game.

Comment: I found what I was looking for but I guess their issue is the scope of the levels is pretty big for a Wii game, whilst many of the levels are simple a lot of them have quite a lot too them. Some like the first bee level have a large core level then many other planets floating around them for the various different stars. It's probably quite a lot to handle for the Wii I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after posting this I found exactly what I was looking for with plenty of other examples :)
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DynamicLoading